# Importing sql file into AWS RDS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Currently I have an EC2 Instance and a RDS (mysql) instance. I exported my database from my local workstation and uploaded it to my EC2 instance and put it in my ec2-user home directory.

I log into the EC2 instance and run this command in the same directory as my projectname.sql file which in this case would be substituted for "backupfile.sql" in the command. After running this command my site was able to successfully connect to the database. I knew this because all my errors on my site disapeared. The issue now is that my tables did not seem to upload.

```
mysql -h host.address.for.rds.server -u rdsusername -p  rdsdatabase < backupfile.sql
```

Running this command:

```
mysql -h host.address.for.rds.server -P 3306 -u rdsusername -p
```

With my correct credentials logs me in to the rds server. I then run:

```
use databasename
show tables
```

But no tables are shown. 
My end goal is to get my localhost database onto AWS RDS by uploading a sql file. If there is an easier way please let me know!This is my first time setting up AWS and these road blocks are killing me.

Answer (score 0):

I use the third party product [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com) to replicate my database into AWS.  It allows you to have connections to multiple databases at the same time and copy between them.  In order to set up a connection to your AWS instance you will need the .pem file on your local machine and have to enable MySQL/Aurora in your Security group on EC2.  There is a some more information [here](http://blog.webyog.com/2009/11/06/amazon-rds-the-beginners-guide/).  Once it is set up it is extremely easy to copy databases or individual tables.

Answer (score 0):

From the [aws documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.SmallExisting.html)

```
sudo mysqldump -u <local_user> \
--databases world \
--single-transaction \
--compress \
--order-by-primary  \
-p <local_password> | mysql -u <RDS_user_name> \
    --port=3306 \
    --host=hostname \
    -p <RDS_password>
```